# Django: Produce QuerySet for related object while keeping an annotation

Tags: django, django-models

I have a complicated data model that involves two related models like this:

```
class A(Model):
    b = ForeignKey(B)
    ...  # does not matter

class B(Model):
    ...  # does not matter

def myquery() -> QuerySet:
    qs = A.objects.filter(...).annotate(x=...)
    # The above is 46 LOC long in reality.
    # I want to return the corresponding Bs
    # plus the annotation x again, as a queryset.
```

I am writing a function that produces a `QuerySet` of `B` objects.
I have written complicated 46 lines of code that produce a `QuerySet` of just the right `A` objects with an important annotation `x` that I need to keep in the result.

All that is left to do is transform the queryset such that it returns the corresponding `B` objects (1-to-1 from the `A` objects) with the `x` annotations reattached.

How?

Comment: Having more details about the query and annotation would help. In general, is there something making it  impossible to rewrite the query on `B` instead?

Comment: @kristaps Perhaps not impossible, but the many attributes from which I compute annotation `x` are all on `A`. If it's too hard, I could go the route of `qs.values('b', 'x')`, but I dislike the more cumbersome processing I will then have to do later to keep the `x` around.

Answer (score 0):

### It's damn complicated...

This appears to do:

```
# from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery
# requires Django 1.11
b_ids = qs.values_list('b', flat=True)
this_x = qs.filter(b=OuterRef('pk')) \
           .values_list('x', flat=True)
return B.objects.filter(pk__in=b_ids) \
                .annotate(x=Subquery(this_x))
```

Not too pretty. Is there a better solution?

(P.S.: The worst part is how difficult the Django documentation makes it to find this solution. It has all the relevant information somewhere, but is badly organized and often too implicit wrt types for my taste.)